# QTableView displaying a subset of rows in a random order

Tags: qt, qtableview, model-view, qabstracttablemodel

I'm looking for a way to have a `QTableView` show a subset of the total rows in the `QAbstractTableModel` in a random order.

I have found `QSortFilterProxyModel` to display a subset of rows (filter). However, it can't do a random order, it can only do sorted (sort).
`QAbstractProxyModel` looked promising, but the editors don't even work when I use that transparantly. Maybe I'm missing something here, but reimplementing `mapToSource` and `mapFromSource` proves insufficient.

What would be the correct way to get this done?
I could obviously do this inside my model, but this feels wrong if it's only for viewing/editor purpose.

Comment: You can subclass `QSortFilterProxyModel` and reimplement its `sort` method to do what you want - create a random order of items and sort according to it.